# OpenEdx nutmeg oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, openedx

I am trying to configure my openedx installation to use third party authentication using google. I got client ID and client secret from google and I followed the instructions here https://discuss.overhang.io/t/social-login-configuration-for-edx-as-plugin-in-tutor/1746 but I still can't see the google button on openedx.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a late reply, but I ran into the same problem today. Hope this reaches anyone else with the same problem.

After some hours of debugging and trying out different stuff, I fixed it by using no **Icon Class** in the Admin panel. I just deleted the **fa-google-plus** text, uploaded my own logo and that did the trick!

I'm guessing the Edx documentation is outdated and the Google icon is not called **fa-google-plus** anymore?